# Visual Studio Remote Linux Headers

Tags: linux, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop an IoT project. I'd like to remote compile on a machine with a bit more horse power so using a full fledge IDE is more responsive.

I was going to try Visual Studio, but the remote headers when I sync causes all headers to fail for intellisense. Even the default project with

```
#include <cstdio>
```

fails intellisense even though it will compile fine.

The files seem to be under usr/include/c++/7.3.0 but for some reason the downloader cuts off the '.3.0' and none of the files appear under that directory.

Any hints on getting it to work? I've tried updating the cache but for the machine, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There have been problems with paths, suggest you report it on the VSLinux github page: https://github.com/microsoft/vslinux/issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New method 'rsync_ssh' doesn't download all headers. You can use old method .zip via sftp_ssh.

**1.** Select your connection
Update from Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager->Remote Headers Intellisense Manager. 
Next click on Explore button.

[image]

**2.** C:\Users[YourUser]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0[IdNumber]
Rename the HeaderCache settings.xml.unused file to settings.xml

[image]

**3.** In the settings.xml file Change the syncMethod to sftp_ssh.

[image]

**4.** Update headers cache from Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager->Remote Headers Intellisense Manager.
**5.** Enjoy.

#### **Before**

[image]

[image]

#### **After**

[image]

[image]

Tested on Visual Studio Community 2017 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview 4.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue still exists in latest VS 2022... and there is no settings file.